# Custom filter to search through JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In angular js filter, if i write "subhadeep" then "pal" then first it filters with the value subhadeep and then it filters the value with pal. But in my requirement i need to design a filter which will return those object which contain either "subhadeep" or "pal" or both.

So filter will return those JSON object which contains either of the value so that i can populate those in ng-repeat.

JSON structure can vary . So i need a code that will search through all fields of each JSON objec. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('myFilter', function(object, requiredValues) {
        var filteredObject = {};
        angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
            if(requiredValues.indexOf(value) !== -1)
                filteredObject[key] = value;
        });
        return filteredObject;
    }
```